# Clicking problem on Firefox web push notifications

Tags: javascript, firefox, push-notification, service-worker, addeventlistener

I have a problem with push notifications on firefox, after sending and receiving push notifications I want to be able to click on them to get to a page linked to the notification, so I made the service worker and it works perfectly on Chrome/Edge. However, on Firefox, when I click on the notification as soon as it's received, it works, but once the service worker is stopped (30s after no event triggered) or if I've closed the browser, when I click on a notification there's no action and the service worker doesn't start up again (unlike Chrome).

My service worker :

```
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log('SW installed');
  event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
  let notification_data = JSON.parse(event.data.text());

  if (event.data) {
    const title = notification_data.title;
    const options = {
      body: notification_data.body,
      icon: notification_data.icon,
      badge: notification_data.badge,
      data: notification_data.url,
    };
    
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
  }
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    openUrl(event.notification.data)
  );
});

async function openUrl(url) {
  const windowClients = await self.clients.matchAll({
    type: "window",
    includeUncontrolled: true,
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
    const client = windowClients[i];
    if (client.url === url && "focus" in client) {
      return client.focus();
    }
  }
  if (self.clients.openWindow) {
    return self.clients.openWindow(url);
  }
  return null;
}
```

I've tried clearing the firefox cache and resetting the configuration to 0 but it still doesn't work. I've tried looking at where the cache is stored to see if the data was deleted when the SW was turned off but I can't find it. I also tried to find out if the 'notificationclick' event was handled differently from Chrome to Firefox. While searching I saw that background.service_worker was not set on firefox yet but I don't know if there is a link. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?